# Django queryset remove all duplicates(not just remove one of them)

Tags: django

for example, I have a `queryset1 = [objects1, objects2, objects2, objects3]`

and I know `queryset1.distinct()` can return `[objects1, objects2, object3]`

but I don't want the objects2 anymore cause there could be some issues

so what I want to get is `[objects1, object3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***annotate*** , ***Count*** the field you want to check, then filter by the count :

```
from django.db.models import Count

    result = Model.objects.all().values('field_to_check_the_dupliate_value').annotate(total = Count('field_to_check_the_dupliate_value')).filter(total__lte=1)
```

**result** will ***return only the value of field you check the dupicate for***. So if you need other field from the model i suggest to do the opposite filter(assuming the duplicate record is far less than not duplicate one), make it as a list, then make new queryset excluding the duplicated value. Example:

```
duplicate = Model.objects.all().values('field_to_check_the_dupliate_value').annotate(total = Count('field_to_check_the_dupliate_value')).filter(total__gt=1)
result = Model.objects.exclude(field_to_check_the_dupliate_value__in = duplicate.values_list('field_to_check_the_dupliate_value', flat=True) )
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the duplicates, and then exclude them from your original queryset:

Here an example:

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then add some test data:

```py
YourModel.objects.create(name="object1")
YourModel.objects.create(name="object2")
YourModel.objects.create(name="object2")
YourModel.objects.create(name="object3")
```

And now the actual code:

```py
from myapp.models import YourModel
from django.db.models import Count

qs = YourModel.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by()
duplicates = qs.filter(count__gt=1)

YourModel.objects.exclude(name__in=duplicates.values_list('name', flat=True))

# Returns: <QuerySet [<Test: object1>, <Test: object3>]>
```